# Is there a defined ordering between dragend and drop events?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) on the HTML5 drag and drop API, two events are fired when an element is dropped:

1. A `drop` event is fired from the drop target
2. A `dragend` event is fired from the source of the drag

In doing a simple test (see snippet), the `drop` event always fires just before the `dragend` event (at least in Chrome) but I can't find anything about the ordering of these events in the spec.

Is the ordering of these events defined, or are they free to fire in either order?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    console.log("drop at " + Date.now());
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

function dragend(ev) {
    console.log("dragend at " + Date.now());
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#drag1 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>Drag the green square in to the red one</div>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" width="100px" height="100px"></div>

<div id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondragend="dragend(event)" width="50px" height="50px">
```

Comment: It is the same order for Firefox

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to the [drag-and-drop processing model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#drag-and-drop-processing-model) specified in the current (updated June 8, 2021) HTML specification, the `drop()` event must fire **before** the `dragend()` event.

The corresponding information is deeply nested in the document, but the section describing the end of the drag operation looks as follows (omissions and emphasis mine):

> Otherwise, if the user ended the drag-and-drop operation (e.g. by
> releasing the mouse button in a mouse-driven drag-and-drop interface),
> or if the `drag` event was canceled, then this will be the last
> iteration. Run the following steps, then stop the drag-and-drop
> operation:
>
> 1. [...]
>    Otherwise, the drag operation might be a success; run these substeps:
>
>    1. Let *dropped* be true.
>    2. If the current target element is a DOM element, fire a DND event named **`drop`** at it; otherwise, use platform-specific
>       conventions for indicating a drop.
>    3. [...]
> 2. Fire a DND event named **`dragend`** at the source node.
> 3. [...]